# Is proxy.conf.json file required when angular and spring boot bundled in single war and deployed on tomcat

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, war

I have bundled angular 8 code and spring boot rest services code into a single war file. During development(before creating war file), everything went smooth, configured proxy.conf.json in package.json scripts=>start. When a request(/api/) is made, all requests are intercepted by proxy.conf.json and then to spring boot server.

My question is, Is proxy.conf.json required when angular + spring boot bundled in single war file and deployed on tomcat. I have used maven frontend plugin to compile angular code and copy the same in dist folder, resources plugin to copy compile code from dist folder to spring boot static folder. Now its complete javascript and rest services code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the official doc at https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server, the proxy config file is specific to the webpack dev server that is used in development for Angular applications.

It is not used and not required in your production environment.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.